# Azure Data Explorer - Could not connect to cluster

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I am following this tutorial.

https://microsoftlearning.github.io/mslearn-synapse/Instructions/Labs/01-Explore-Azure-Synapse.html

In the `Data Explorer` section, I am getting this error

```
Could not connect to cluster

Principal 'msauser=myEmailIdForAzure' is not authorized to perform operation 'VersionShowCommand' on 'https://adxiy0pzgx.synapseiy0pzgx.kusto.azuresynapse.net:443/'.
```

How could I fix the issue?

Comment: Is it still relevant?

Comment: No answer. I haven't been able to fix the problem yet.

Comment: What do you mean "No answer"?. Is the cluster alive?

Comment: Yes, still relevant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Data Explorer` window/tab was opened, I was not in the correct directory. I switched directory by clicking on profile icon on top right corner and added the correct tenant id (corresponding to my subscription's default directory)

Comment: Correct answer. To retrieve the correct tenant ID look for your 'directory' on your profile (top-right) in your synapse workspace window...